# Calling function inside function

Tags: raphael, typescript

I'm trying to learn (develop) some game using HTML5 and TypeScript. I write this part of code:

```
class GameMap {
    private sheet: RaphaelPaper;
    private tiles: Tile[];
    constructor() {
        this.tiles = [];
        this.sheet = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
    }

    render() {
        var tileWidth = 20;
        var tileHeight = 20;

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                this.tiles.push(new Tile(i, j));
                var rectangle = this.sheet.rect(i * tileWidth, j * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                rectangle.hover(this.tileMouseOn(), this.tileMouseOut(), rectangle, rectangle);
            }
        }
    }

    tileMouseOn() {
        this.attr({ 'stroke-width': 1 });
    }

    tileMouseOut() {
        this.attr({ 'stroke-width': 0 });
    }
}
```

The problem is with `rectangle.hover()` function. I recieve following error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
Could not apply type 'Function' to argument 1 which is of type 'void'.
```

What is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hover()` is expecting to have function reference as 2 first arguments. Try with this :

```
rectangle.hover(this.tileMouseOn, this.tileMouseOut, rectangle, rectangle);
```

Comment: Beautiful :) Thanks a lot. I tried everything, except this "delegates" :P